# DNS: migrating FROM Google Email + Google App hosted website TO Google Email + 3rd party hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, g-suite, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I inherited a DNS/website/email scenario I don't understand.

#
I need to modify DNS records so that email integrated with Google Apps is not altered, but so that web traffic goes to a 3rd party. Currently the web traffic goes to a Google App Engine account (under the previous developers personal account).

On the receiving end, I have a static IP address and the nameservers for the host the web account is on. I just need to know what to do with them.

I tried changing the A record, but that broke the Google Email integration. I tried specifying the current A record IP in the MX Host fields, and that was bad, too.

#
Current info:

#
A (Host)
@
216.239.32.21

CNAME (Alias)
e
email.secureserver.net

email
email.secureserver.net

ftp
@

imap
imap.secureserver.net

mail
pop.secureserver.net

mobilemail
mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net

pda
mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net

pop
pop.secureserver.net

smtp
smtp.secureserver.net

webmail
webmail.secureserver.net

www
ghs.google.com

MX (Mail Exchanger)
20
@
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

30
@
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

10
@
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

40
@
ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

50
@
ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM

TXT (Text)
@
google-site-verification=REDACTED

#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you changed the A record, that should not have broken the Google Apps email. Do you mean your users were unable to access the web interface? If so, tell them to use:

http://mail.google.com/a/YOUR_DOMAIN.COM

If you are using mail clients (like Outlook), test with the url above. The A record has no impact on the actual flow of email for Google Apps.

For your new host, you were right to change the A record for YOUR_DOMAIN.COM and www to the new static IP.

You want to leave all the MX records. These are what directs your mail to the Google mail servers.

NOTE: The records: email, imap, mail, mobilemail, pop, smtp, webmail and the CNAME e (possible pda as well) all appear to be legacy records from before you migrated to Google Apps. If you are not doing some mail redirection within Google Apps or some other fancy setup, these likely can be removed. My recommendation would be to remove one as a test if you are unsure -- once you have straightened out the other issues.

NOTE: Once you get this sorted out, I would strongly recommend a SPF record be added. See:

https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723